# помогите решить задачу за короткое алгоритмическое время

Tags: c++, олимпиада, арифметика, теория-чисел

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1.5.4. Факториал по модулю
Ограничение времени `1 секунда`
Ограничение памяти  `64Mb`
Ввод    стандартный ввод или `input.txt`
Вывод   стандартный вывод или `output.txt`
Во входном файле задано целое положительное число `N`, не превосходящее `10⁹`. Найдите остаток от деления числа  (произведения всех чисел от `1` до `N`) на `10⁶+3`.

Формат ввода
Первая строка входного файла содержит одно целое число `N` (`1 ≤ N ≤ 10⁹`).

Формат вывода
Выведите одно целое число — ответ к задаче.

**Пример 1:**
`Ввод - 3 ; Вывод - 6`

**Пример 2:**
`Ввод - 10 ; Вывод - 628791`

Comment: Намек: для чисел, больших 1000003, остаток нулевой!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Трудности у человека вызывает использование символов Unicode типа ⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ или хотя бы записи в стиле TeX'а 10^9. Ильяс, обратите внимание — это я вам пишу, а не Станиславу :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Очевидно, что при N >= 1000003 значение N! делится на 1000003.
2. Очевидно, что при N < 1000003 значение N! на 1000003 нацело не делится, т.к. 1000003 — число простое.
3. Очевидно, что если число А с остатком от деления на Р, равным а, умножить на В, то остаток от произведения равен остатку от произведения а*В от деления на Р.
4. Очевидно, что произведение двух чисел порядка 1000000 в 4-байтный тип `int` не влезет, и надо использовать `long long`.

А из этих очевидностей очевидным образом получается... ну, у меня с красивым форматированием :) — 8 строк кода, которые не привожу, чтобы не лишать вас удовольствия написать их самостоятельно...